# put a absolute positioned div inside slider images

Tags: css, slider, css-position

I have a slider in div `#slides` .

```
<div id="slides">
          <img src="img/slide-1.jpg" />
          <img src="img/slide-2.jpg" />
          <img src="img/slide-3.jpg" />
          <img src="img/slide-4.jpg" />
    </div>
```

`#slides {
      display: none;
      position:relative;
    }`

Now I want to put a div `.slide-helpext` within the slide images showing some texts, How I should place the div?

```
.slide-helpext
{
    position:absolute;
    top:30%;
    left:60px;

}
```

EDIT:
I placed the slide div as below :

```
<div id="slides">
          <img src="img/example-slide-1.jpg" alt="Photo by: Missy S Link: http://www.flickr.com/photos/listenmissy/5087404401/">
          <div class="slide-helpext">1</div>
          <img src="img/example-slide-2.jpg" alt="Photo by: Daniel Parks Link: http://www.flickr.com/photos/parksdh/5227623068/">
          <div class="slide-helpext">2</div>
          <img src="img/example-slide-3.jpg" alt="Photo by: Mike Ranweiler Link: http://www.flickr.com/photos/27874907@N04/4833059991/">
          <div class="slide-helpext">3</div>
          <img src="img/example-slide-4.jpg" alt="Photo by: Stuart SeegerLink: http://www.flickr.com/photos/stuseeger/97577796/">
          <div class="slide-helpext">4</div>
    </div>
```

But is sliding the number then the image, eg a blank screen with 1, then the corresponding image !

Comment: is all the images have the same width with the #slides container?

Comment: #slides { display: none; position:relative; } won't show anything :)

Comment: totally agreed with @GCyrillus

Comment: Same width and same height.

Comment: Slider working fine ! @Qiqi and GC

Comment: Okay, first of all, this markup has error  <img src="img/slide-1.jpg" /">. Supposely it should be <img src="img/slide-1.jpg" />

Comment: Because you see the structure, it will display img first, then div, then img again. You should put both the img and the div inside a new div container, so it can be shown together. See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slider">
    <div class="slide">
       <img src="img/slide-1.jpg" />
       <span class="slide-helpext">Caption goes here</span>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
       <img src="img/slide-2.jpg" />
       <span class="slide-helpext">Caption goes here</span>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
       <img src="img/slide-3.jpg" />
       <span class="slide-helpext">Caption goes here</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.slide{
    position:relative;
}
.slide-helpext{
    position:absolute;
    top:30%;
    left:60px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Abaziz..its working nicely after I put the image and caption together within a div.

Answer (score 0):

Place it next to it, and give it a negative margin that makes it overlap the image. You can't actually put other elements inside images hierarchically, but you can make them look so.

```
<div id="images">
    <img src="image.png" />
    <div class="text">Title</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.text {
    margin-top: -30px;
    height:30px;
}
```